# What to do whenever one callback gets an error and then the below nested ones didn't execute in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, async-await, callback

While using the nested `callbacks` or `promises` or `async/await` where one set of tasks gets executed first which are in `await` condition and then only it proceeds further on **success**; I would like to know then what to do if an **error** occured in between to any **middle task**?

Since after that none tasks will be executed as the operations will come to **halt** now.
But due to this when this end point is called the whole process becomes incomplete since some initial tasks gets executed and comes to halt in between and remaining tasks also get paused/stopped.

So this whole situation becomes incomplete and shabby.

How to deal with this?

Below is the example of code I am dealing with multiple routes in my project where I am using the nested callbacks. And when one tasks gets error the below whole process gets stopped since error has been occured.

```
  router.route('/addTasks-approve').get(function(req, res) {


                      User.updateMany({'Addtasks.commonID':req.query.id},
                         {$set: {"Addtasks.$.width" :'250px',
                          "Addtasks.$.height" :'32px',
                          "Addtasks.$.background" :'linear-gradient(45deg, #0f3443, #34e89e)',
                          "Addtasks.$.border_radius" :'10px / 5px',
                         "Addtasks.$.status" :req.query.text}},
                        function (error, success) {
                              if (!error) {
                                console.log("Approved color set!");
                                User.findOne({tag:'Admin','Addtasks.commonID':req.query.id},function (error, dataAdmin) {
                                      if (error) {
                                          console.log("error = "+ error);
                                          res.end('{"msg" : "Some error occurred", "status" : 700}');
                                      }
                                      else {
                                        dataAdmin.Addtasks.forEach(element => {
                                          if(element.commonID == req.query.id)
                                          {
                                     User.findOneAndUpdate({tag:'Client','Addtasks.commonID':req.query.id},
                                     {$push: {'Addtasks.$.Bigpaths4Clients':{$each : element.Bigpaths4Clients}},
                                      $set: {"Addtasks.$.background" :'linear-gradient(45deg, #1E6305, #BDFF00)',
                                             "Addtasks.$.status" :'Done'}},
                                        function (error, data) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                console.log("error = "+ error);
                                                res.end('{"msg" : "Unable to add the Task", "status" : 700}');
                                              }
                                              else {
                                                console.log("Addtasks added to Client's dashboard succesfully");
                                                sendMails2Client(data.email, element.topic, 'In Progress', 'Done');
                                                sendMails2User(dataAdmin.email, element.topic, 'Done', 'Approved');
                                                User.findOne({tag:'Admin','Addtasks.commonID':req.query.id},function (error, dataWriter) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          console.log("error = "+ error);
                                                          res.end('{"msg" : "Some error occurred", "status" : 700}');
                                                      }
                                                      else {
                                                        sendMails2User(dataWriter.email, element.topic, 'Done', 'Approved');
                                                        res.end('{"success" : "success", "status" : 200}');
                                                      }
                                                    })
                                              }
                                      })
                                    }
                                  });
                                }
                              });
                              }
                              else {
                                res.end('{"msg" : "Unable to set the status and color for Approved", "status" : 700}');
                              }
                            });
                                                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

for this situation I prefer you use `Transactions` in mongoose, transactions are new in MongoDB 4.0 and Mongoose 5.2.0. Transactions let you execute multiple operations in isolation and potentially undo all the operations if one of them fails. This guide will get you started using transactions with Mongoose, check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html),because if you have collection multiple update, in the middle of task occur a error, the `rollback` must be done: it's a example to help you

```
  try {
    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
    sess.startTransaction();
    await User.deleteMany({'xyz': 999}).session(sess);
    await createdUser.save({ session: sess });
    await user.save({ session: sess });
    await sess.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    );
```

Comment: Okay I will look upon this. Also Am I handling the errors correct here when I am using the nested callbacks? Is this the correct way of handling the errors? I am using the callback way of handling the tasks in all the routes in my project and whenever error occurs the page stopped loading and it gives heroku logs Application error. Instead of that I want to throw an error alert on UI to the user that an error has occured. Please try later. How to do that?

Comment: Also Please tell me how to use the Mongoose transactions with nested callbacks ? Since the documentation is given while one is using the async/await. :(

Comment: Yes! But I just wanted if you could have transitioned my whole question code using Transactions along with async/await.

Comment: Also please have a look upon this if you can answer this too and then will accept both the answers and upvote it. Thanks! –

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809059/how-to-send-an-error-alert-in-ui-whenever-an-error-occurs-on-server-side-in-node

Comment: Your code is easily converted to async/await , why not use async/await ???because if you want to use transaction, your code should be based on async/await

Comment: How to use/include the {session} with the methods which are being called inside the routes?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noticed, working with callbacks quickly leads to code that is hard to maintain. This is known as the pyramid of doom.

You can rewrite to code to use Promises and async/await. This makes the code easier to follow and understand.

All APIs that use callbacks can be rewritten using Promises.

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Create a new Promise.
  aFunctionWithCallback((err, result) => { // Call the function.
    if (err) { // On error, reject.
      reject(err);
    } else { // On result, resolve.
      resolve(result);
    }
  });
```

Node.js has a utility function to do this, `Util.promisify`. Many APIs already provide a promisified API or there may be an additional library for this.

You can then just use try/catch and async/await:

```
try {
  await updateMany(...);
  await findOne(...);
  await findOneAndUpdate(...);
} catch (err)
  // Handle error.
}
```

Of course you can use multiple try/catch blocks if you need to handle errors from individual functions.